# Выбор между которых/которые

Tags: склонение, падежи

Увидел такое рекламное объявление: «Готовим уникальные авторские коктейли, которых не найти в меню.»

Но если смотреть на таблицу падежей в мн.ч винительный падеж, неодуш, в предложении должно быть «коктейлей, которые не найти в меню.»

Корректно ли составлено это предложение?

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

*Готовим уникальные авторские коктейли, **которых не найти в меню.***

Правило Розенталя:

[§201. **Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

При переходных глаголах с отрицанием в одних случаях явно преобладает употребление **родительного** падежа дополнения, в других – употребление **винительного** падежа, в третьих – наблюдается факультативное их использование.

1. **Родительный** падеж, имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции значение **подчеркнутого отрицания**, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:

(4)  при глаголах ***иметь, получать, доставать*** и т.п., которые в сочетании с частицей ***не*** приобретают значение полного отрицания, например: не имеет комнаты, не получил приказа, не достал билета, не приобрел нужных вещей.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

В Музее хранились также редкие книги, журналы, газеты, листовки и брошюры эмигрантского издания, **которых не найти** в других библиотеках мира. [Политическая хроника (18.02.2006) // «Наша страна» (Аргентина), 2006]

В эту группу входит как творог, так и незрелые мягкие сыры, ароматизированные сыры и различные местные сыры, **которых не найти** в других регионах. [Корми меня по-французски (2004) // «Мир & Дом. Residence», 15.04.2004]